# jni4net - System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingException

Tags: java, c#, .net, remoting, jni4net

I am trying to use a Java / .NET bridge to communicate with a server. The bridge was built with [jni4net](http://jni4net.sourceforge.net/) and seem to work (so far).

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    File sibDll = new File("SibKernel.Client.j4n.dll");

    Bridge.setVerbose(true);
    Bridge.setClrVersion("v20");    

    try {
      Bridge.init();

      Bridge.LoadAndRegisterAssemblyFrom(sibDll);

    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (SibKernelHelper.isConfigured() == false) {
      SibKernelHelper.Configure();
    }

    IMasterBoardManager mstrBoardMngr = SibKernelHelper.GetMasterBoardManager();
  }
```

I really don't have any idea what the problem could be. Does anyone have experiance with a problem like this?

Here is the full exception stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingException: Cannot load type 'net.sf.jni4net.jni.IJvmProxy, jni4net.n-0.8.6.0, Version=0.8.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=134a23405600bab4'.

Server stack trace: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.MethodCall.ResolveMethod(Boolean bThrowIfNotResolved)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.MethodCall..ctor(Object handlerObject, BinaryMethodCallMessage smuggledMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryMethodCall.ReadArray(Object[] callA, Object handlerObject)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.Deserialize(HeaderHandler handler, __BinaryParser serParser, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream, HeaderHandler handler, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.CoreChannel.DeserializeBinaryRequestMessage(String objectUri, Stream inputStream, Boolean bStrictBinding, TypeFilterLevel securityLevel)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.BinaryServerFormatterSink.ProcessMessage(IServerChannelSinkStack sinkStack, IMessage requestMsg, ITransportHeaders requestHeaders, Stream requestStream, IMessage& responseMsg, ITransportHeaders& responseHeaders, Stream& responseStream)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at net.sf.jni4net.jni.IJvmProxy.get_JvmHandle()
   at net.sf.jni4net.utils.Convertor.FullC2J[TBoth](JNIEnv env, TBoth obj)
   at SibKernel.Client.__SibKernelHelper.GetMasterBoardManager6(IntPtr __envp, JniLocalHandle __class)
    at sibkernel.client.SibKernelHelper.GetMasterBoardManager(Native Method)
    at client.SIBClient.main(SIBClient.java:28)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to instantiate some type inherited or dependent on jni4net, but the problem happens on the other side of your .NET remoting.
Probably you are passing instance of Java object as argument of the remoting call.

Comment: Hi Pavel! :) Well, the code that is executed is assembled in .dll files that I bridged with jni4net. At the moment there is nothing created. Only three calls are executed: `isConfigured()`, `Configure()` and `GetMasterBoardManager()`. These calls seem to work so far since `GetMasterBoardManager()` is able to start the server. After the server started something seems to crash. I still have no idea what the problem is or where it occurs..

Comment: Do I have to make any additions to the server that is called remotely? I don't get the problem. The code is called and executed. The server does not need to know about any jni4net assembly, does he? I was expecting the code - once it is executed - to return to the Java application. I really need to get this run ..